# Can Solidity access the gaslimit (not just the remaining gas)?

Tags: solidity, gas-limit

Solidity has access to the *remaining* gas via [`msg.gas`](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties) which changes from line to line. But I would like to know if I can access the *initially* submitted gasLimit. Is that possible in Solidity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No,** the transaction gas limit is unavailable in Solidity (though the [`block.gaslimit`](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/units-and-global-variables.html#block-and-transaction-properties) is).  A suggestion is to file an [EIP](https://github.com/ethereum/eips/issues) with your use cases and let the community provide input.

Comment: I came up with this when answering this question: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/18349/accessing-modifying-options-parameters-in-contract/18368#18368 I cannot come up with a use case that requires it but feel there might be some. The issue is: The delta between the actually set gas limit and `msg.gas` is irrevocably spent in any case. I dont see a reason why I'd need to act upon what I cant change anymore. If you give me one I'd write the EIP gladly ;)